Flutter Error: Could not find the correct Provider above BlocBuilder Widget
I am encountering the following error in my Flutter application:

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this BlocBuilder<GetPostBloc, GetPostState> Widget
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this BlocBuilder<MyUserBloc, MyUserState> Widget

I have provided the code for GetPostBloc, MyUserBloc, and the widget where these classes are used.
GetPostBloc code:
class GetPostBloc extends Bloc<GetPostEvent, GetPostState> {
  PostRepository _postRepository;

  GetPostBloc({
    required PostRepository postRepository
  }) : _postRepository = postRepository,
        super(GetPostInitial()) {
    on<GetPosts>((event, emit) async {
      emit(GetPostLoading());
      try {
        List<Post> posts = await _postRepository.getPost();
        emit(GetPostSuccess(posts));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(GetPostFailure());
      }
    });
  }
}

MyUserBloc code:
class MyUserBloc extends Bloc<MyUserEvent, MyUserState> {
  final UserRepository _userRepository;

  MyUserBloc({
    required UserRepository myUserRepository
  }) : _userRepository = myUserRepository,
        super(const MyUserState.loading()) {
    on<GetMyUser>((event, emit) async {
      try {
        MyUser myUser = await _userRepository.getMyUser(event.myUserId);
        emit(MyUserState.success(myUser));
      } catch (e) {
        log(e.toString());
        emit(const MyUserState.failure());
      }
    });
  }
}

In a different file, I have an ElevatedButton that navigates to HomeScreen:
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    // Navigate to Login
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MaterialApp(
          home: HomeScreen(),
      )
      ),
    );
  },
)

Here is the HomeScreen widget where GetPostBloc and MyUserBloc are used:
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
        floatingActionButton: BlocBuilder<MyUserBloc, MyUserState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if(state.status == MyUserStatus.success) {
              return FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
      // ...
      body: BlocBuilder<GetPostBloc, GetPostState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
        if(state is GetPostSuccess) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: state.posts.length,
          // ...
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

I have tried wrapping the Scaffold with the respective BlocProvider widgets, but the error persists. I have also followed other proposed solutions, but none have worked so far.
I tried to resolve the error by wrapping the Scaffold widget in my HomeScreen with the respective BlocProvider widgets for GetPostBloc and MyUserBloc. I was expecting this to provide the necessary context for the BlocBuilder widgets to access the corresponding blocs and retrieve the required data.
However, the error persisted, and I was unable to get the desired result. I also attempted to follow other proposed solutions from various resources, but none of them worked for my specific case.
